# Meaning of "2 * np.random.rand(100,1)"

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm a begginer on programming.
I tried running an simple linear regression example in a book. Y=4*X+6
I have set `np.random.seed(0)`.
When creating X, the code in the book used `2 * np.random.rand(100,1)`.
I created X1, X2, X3 in the following way. Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)  
X1 = 2 * np.random.rand(5,1)  
X2 = np.random.rand(5,1)  
X3 = 2 * X2  
print('X1= ', X1)  
print('X2= ', X2)  
print('X3= ', X3)
```

I have questions here.

1. What is the meaning of multiply 2 with np.random.rand(100,1)? As a result of running the above code, it seems that it is not simply doubling the value or doubling the size.
2. And why the results of X1 and X3 are different?

Comment: It should just double all the values.

Comment: X1 and X3 are different because each time you call `np.random.rand()` you get a different random array.

Comment: Call `np.random.seed(0)` again before assigning X2, then `X1` and `X3` will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. It doubles the value.  How do you think that it doesn't?
2. They're different because you called for a random array in two different locations.  Why would you expect `random` to return the same values on two successive calls?  The sequence would hardly be random, then.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: X1 = 2 * np.random.rand(5,1)
    ...: X2 = np.random.rand(5,1)
    ...: X3 = 2 * X2

In [45]: X1
Out[45]: 
array([[1.09762701],
       [1.43037873],
       [1.20552675],
       [1.08976637],
       [0.8473096 ]])
In [46]: X2
Out[46]: 
array([[0.64589411],
       [0.43758721],
       [0.891773  ],
       [0.96366276],
       [0.38344152]])
In [47]: X3
Out[47]: 
array([[1.29178823],
       [0.87517442],
       [1.783546  ],
       [1.92732552],
       [0.76688304]])
```

`X2` values are between 0 and 1.  `X3` values are twice the `X2` ones, and between 0 and 2.  `X1` values are different numbers, but also between 0 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are expecting np.random.rand() to return the same value because you are setting the seed. This is a misunderstanding. Setting the seed *once* means that, from them on, it will return a sequence of random values. If you then set *the same* seed again, it will afterwards return the same sequence. Try this instead:

```
np.random.seed(0)  
X1 = np.random.rand(5,1) 
 
np.random.seed(0)  
X2 = np.random.rand(5,1)
```

X1 will be equal to X2, as each is the beginning of the sequence associated with seed 0.

Now, try this:

```
np.random.seed(0)  
X1 = np.random.rand(5,1) 
Y1 = np.random.rand(5,1)
 
np.random.seed(0)  
X2 = np.random.rand(5,1)
Y1 = np.random.rand(5,1)
```

Now X1=X2  and Y1=Y2. But X1 != Y1 (unless you randomly draw the same thing twice).

To answer your first question, yes -- you're multiplying the result of the random draw by 2, so it will now return elements from 0 to 2 rather than 0 to 1.

Now, it may be that you want two identical random number generators without resetting the seed each time. If this is the case, initialize two numpy.random.RandomState:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html?highlight=numpy%20random%20randomstate#numpy.random.RandomState

Or one of their new generators. Then you can initialize them both with the same seed, and draw from one for a while, then draw from another that is still 'earlier' in the random sequence for that seed.

Answer (score 0):

1. The meaning of multiply by 2 is that it is doubling the values in the ndarray ( the result of np.random.rand(5,1)) You never see the original values, you only see the doubled values assigned to X1
2. If you call np.random.rand(5,1) you get random numbers each time you make the call so they will not match that often, because they are random.